# Edit and Add New in joomla custom component conflict

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I've started to make my own custom component following a cookbook for joomla in making a component. All are ok but when i tried to edit an existing data it automatically add again a new data same as the data edited. What is the problem with this? really need help here. Sorry for my bad english.. thank you.

Comment: Can we see some related code ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and spent hours to figure out the issue. However, at last I noticed that I have the equal sign (=) missing in my form action URL.

Previously it was like this;

`<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&layout=edit&id' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="section-form">`

So I changed it to;

`<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_mycomponent&layout=edit&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="section-form">`

Note the missing (=) next to the *id* parameter on the URL.